# Why am I getting the error "Object ... was not found" when importing a dump?

Tags: oracle, import, dump

I want to import a dump file but I have this error:

```
Import: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Feb 22 07:56:35 2023
Version 19.16.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39166: Object HOSTTEST.OOD was not found or could not be exported or imported.
```

My command line:

```
impdp "'/ as sysdba'" directory=IMP dumpfile=SCHEMAS_FULL_27032020%U.DMP \
logfile=IMP_OOD_LOG.log tables=Hosttest.OOD remap_schema=Hosttest:Hosttest \
table_exists_action=replace
```

I confirm my schema exists:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: The schema may exist, but is there the table `HOSTTEST.OOD` in the dump file? How did you check that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.